# How to pass a data from Controller to View in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

How to pass a data from Controller to View in CodeIgniter?

Controller

```
<?php  
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');   
class Hello extends CI_Controller {       
    public function index()  
    {  
        $data['hello']= "helloooo";
        $this->load->view('hello_world');  
    }  
}
```

Comment: please use google for read documentation of codeigniter...

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Comment: in controller `$this->load->view('hello_world', $data);` in view `echo $hello`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');   
class Hello extends CI_Controller {       
    public function index()  
    {  
        $data['hello']= "helloooo";
        $this->load->view('hello_world',$data);  
    }  
}
```

in your view

```
echo $hello;
```

and visit https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

class Hello extends CI_Controller {  

    public function index()  
    {  
        $data['hello']= "helloooo";
        $this->load->view('hello_world',$data);  
    }  
}
```

in view page hello_world

```
<?php
echo $hello;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data as an argument while loading the view.

```
$data['hello']= "helloooo";
$this->load->view('hello_world', $data);
```